# Calculate value where 0 is -50 and 1 is 50 in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm really bad at math, and cannot for the life of me figure out this seemingly easy problem.

I have a value, which varies between 0 and 1 (with decimals), I need to calculate this value so that

- If the value is 0, the calculation should return -50
- if the value is
  0.5, the calculation should return 0
- if the value is 1, the calculation should return 50

Why do I need this? I'm creating an equalizer, and I want my faders represent both negative and positive values. When the fader is on the middle of the rail, its value is 0.5

Here's a picture, pay attention to the +12 and -12 labels:

[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is it html5 range input? try `max="50"` & `min="-50"` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply multiply by 100 and subtract 50

Example:

`a = b*100-50`

You *might* want to use `Math.round` to make it a rounded number

Comment: Wow, it was that simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: Side question, how can I reverse this equation? So 50 becomes 1, 0 becomes 0.5, etc

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Just reverse the operations. The last operation was to subtract 50, so the first would be to add 50. The other operation was multiply by 100, so the next would be to divide by 100. So basically `b = (a+50)/100`... However if `a` might be a string this will be safer `b = (parseInt(a)+50)/100`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to subtract 0.5 and multiply the result with 100 for the wanted range.

```js
function scale(f) {
    return (f - 0.5) * 100;
}

console.log(scale(0));
console.log(scale(0.5));
console.log(scale(1));
```